# Merging visualization with timestamp

Tags: kibana

I have the bar chart that looks exactly the way I want.

https://search-test01-uwyuzluuwezhhbeusk3od5mfti.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/app/kibana#/visualize/

(Visualization name : myvs1)

It has IP address as X-axis and event-names count as Y axis. But how do I know the date on which the IP address was logged?

Is it possible to easily integrate visualizations to Timelion chart?

Comment: You should not leave your Kibana app open to anyone.

Comment: Why? This data is not confidential. I am going to delete it anyway. Is there any other risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the date by following below mentioned steps:-

1. Open your already saved visualization.
2. Under buckets, click on Add Sub-Buckets.
3. Select bucket type as X-Axis.
4. Mention sub-aggregation as Date Histogram.
5. Specify field as @timestamp or any other custom field which contains date/time information.

Your visualization will now showcase the date/time.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Is it possible to somehow link the same IP addresses or should I create a new visualization for this?

Comment: If you are using your existing visualization & adding the above-mentioned steps, then it would be an addition to existing visualization wherein all previous things will remain same but date/time will be added.